# Content management system for graphics?

Tags: content-management-system

I am researching CMS systems, something I know little about. I am an animator and generate large numbers of files and have many source files that I use. There are so many its become difficult to manage them all and keep some organization. Can someone suggest an Open Source CMS solution that could aid in organizing these files.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure about open source ones - Extensis Portfolio has been around for a long time in both single and server versions. I've used the community version of KnowledgeTree but it's a general document management system and a bit of a pain to set up.

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, these systems are called "digital asset management systems" when they're not about text but about images.

An overview about open-source ones can be found [here](http://www.opensourcedigitalassetmanagement.org/)

Comment: In addition to open source DAM systems you should look at Cloud based solutions.

Comment: @Jeff: what's an example and why is cloud based vs. server I'm assuming important?

Answer (score 0):

[Razuna](http://www.razuna.org/) looks quite good, I'm looking for a similar solution - though i probably won't have trillions of textures files or something, I do have loads of .psd/.ai/.indd formats, which a number of systems offer thumbnail preview to a certain degree.

One thing to look out for is whether the system can handle/use/manipulate [IPTC](http://www.iptc.org/site/Home/) metadata, basically what this means is when metadata is embedded in an asset, the system can present that to you in a digestable format. An example of this is Google's Picassa which allows search indexing on this data. Also a number of stock asset sites both use and produce this data in their asset sets - so when you download an image for example, it comes pre-tagged with "woman, standing, smiling, photo, office" so you only have to add your own tags on top, for example "telecoms project, overview module".

Again, if you're generating a swathe of files from your output then it may depend on the nature of your file output as to what kind of versioning/management you need?

If, for example, you have output that is made up of a bunch of source files, some of which are program-specific and some of which are linked assets, then you might want to put the whole lot under version control ([PlasticSCM](http://www.plasticscm.com) or Subversion perhaps) and "exclude" graphic files by their file type. Then, use something like Razuna to upload, hold and display your graphic files.

I noticed with Razuna that you can organise things by category, and assign multiple categories - that is, you have 1 set of files but multiple views of them. That's why I liked Razuna, though to be honest the demo crapped out but it could've been because I changed email and profile data half way through the trial.

Interested to know how you go in your search and what you've found to be useful!

Answer (score 0):

We're looking for something as well, preferably cloud-based, but that's not a requirement.

We're looking right now at Razuna. It has a lot of great features. The organization seems very flexilble, which is great. The

But it doesn't seem very mature in some ways. The development team I think is small. Some features don't work reliably (e.g., uploading additional versions of an asset [such as different resolutions] works intermittently and only with IE as far as I can tell.)

So if anyone has any other systems worth a look I'd be glad to hear about them.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, Razuna was just too immature for us. It's a great effort. The dev team is obviously talented and sincere. In a couple of years they may well have a great product. I wish them luck.

We've settled on a commercial service, WebDAM. It some ways it's very comprehensive and does a lot of things well. The price is not too bad, and there's a nice API to program against, so we will be able to lean on it heavily for image selection and then incorporate it into our automated processes, grabbing images as needed programmatically.

In on other ways it a little maddening. The UI, in particular, could use a lot of work to make it easier to use for the average person. It was clearly designed by programmers. A lot of UI niceties that would not be that hard to add are missing. Obvious things like boxes with data being too small while a lot of screen real estate goes unused.

The keyword capability is useful but there doesn't have obvious things like synonyms and stemming when you search. This will make things harder on our users and will have to be planned carefully to make sure it's as useful as it can be.

We're still just in the planning stages, so not sure how it will fly once we go live, but we're going to give it a shot. You might want to have a look at it. But they have a much more mature development effort going on and more support for the customer, which swayed us in the end.